# subir api rest a heroku mediante gitHub

Tags: javascript, nodejs, git, heroku

tengo entendido que si hago un deploy de mi servidor en heroku mediante gitHub, al hacer un `git push -u origin master` heroku lee los cambios y no hace falta hacer mas nada, ya queda en el servidor, pero estoy teniendo un problema al querer levantar mi servidor, mi api esta escrita en typescript, voy a dejar los archivos importante,

> este es mi `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "tsc-watch --onSuccess \"node dist/index.js\"",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
}
```

obviamente no coloco mas detalles por que no lo veo necesario.

> Mi `.gitignore` no tiene muchas cosas

```
# dependencies
/node_modules

# production
/tsconfig.json
```

esta es la url de la api `https://aidyfabackend.herokuapp.com/` pero si entran veran un error de heroku, intente ver que proglemas eran simplemente observando la consola de heroku, pero al hacer un `heroku logs --tail` me da el sigueinte error

```
 »   Error: You do not have access to the app aidyfaapi.
 »
 »   Error ID: forbidden
```

no entiendo por que no me da acceso, ya que inicie sesion desde el browser y tambien desde la consola, si necesitan mas informacion se las brindare con el objetivo de poder solucionar este problema, muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Tu comando `start` hace referencia a un archivo `index.js` (el código ya transpilado). Por lo que primero que nada tienes que verificar que el deploy este haciendo lo propio con el comando `build`. De ser así, sería bueno que proporciones más detalles en lo que respecta al proceso de deploy, ya que todo parece indicar que tu código no está llegando a Heroku (lo cual puedes verificar desde consola en Heroku).

Comment: Tuve un problema con la pc, en cuanto restaure el sistema seguiré con el deploy, gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Por nada, espero que puedas dar con el problema y solucionarlo